# how can i replace part of file from another file

Tags: python, file, replace, line, multiple-columns

i have a problem to replace two columns from one file to another two columns in another file. the first file contains 29 lines and two columns, while the 2nd file is huge file with around 1400 lines and different columns.
 the first file looks like this:

```
    ag-109    3.905E-07  
    am-241    1.121E-06  
    am-243    7.294E-09  
    cs-133    1.210E-05  
    eu-151   2.393E-08  
    eu-153   4.918E-07  
    gd-155   2.039E-08  
    mo-95   1.139E-05  
    nd-143  9.869E-06 
      ..............
      .............
```

the 2nd file looks like this:

```
 u-234       101  0  7.471e-06   293   end  
 u-235       101  0  0.0005265   293   end  
 u-236       101  0  0.0001285   293   end  
 u-238       101  0  0.02278     293   end  
 np-237      101  0  1.018e-05   293   end  
 pu-238      101  0  2.262e-06   293   end  
 pu-239      101  0  0.000147    293   end  
 .........  
 .......
 # the first 29 lines of column1 repeated, and each 29 lines, has one value 
  of column 2.  
  from "101" 29 times, then "102" 29 lines,.... till "1018"
  as below.
 .    
 u-234       1018  0  7.471e-06  293   end  
 u-235       1018  0  0.0005265  293   end  
 u-236       1018  0  0.0001285  293   end  
 u-238       1018  0  0.02278    293   end  
 np-237      1018  0  1.018e-05  293   end  
 pu-238      1018  0  2.262e-06  293   end 

 after the "1018" 
 file2 text continue like this 

    u-234       201 0  8.856E-06 293   end 
    u-235       201 0  7.832E-04 293   end 
    u-236       201 0  8.506E-05 293   end
```

i want to stop replacing the columns when column  2 is equal to  "201"  until the end of the file.

///***  it must be noted that the rest of file2 is completely different text 
and continues with another texts and numbers with in different columns lengths 
 ********\.

In addition : \\ file1 contains 29 lines, i have multiple files similar to file1 all of their columns must be replaced to file2 columns in order. 
to clarify: 
     if you see in file2 column 2 there is " 101"  so this value repeated for 29 
     times which is related to file1. 
     it will continue until file1_18 to replace in the lines of "1018" in file2

i wish i clarified enough, it is a bit difficult to make it clear for me.

i tried to change column one of file1 with column 1 in file2, and column 2 in file1 to column 3 in file 2.

i faced two problems:
1- I could't replace the columns
2- how to write the the whole file after changing the columns.

i have tried to read the both files and split them in columns, then reading specific columns with conditions.

i also have tried to convert the files into *.csv but it messed up the spaces and it needs to be run with system code with specific extension.

```
  with open('100_60.inp') as f:

       while True:

          line = f.readline()
          if not line:
               break
          columns=re.split(r"\s+",line.strip())
          if len(columns)==6 and columns[5]=='end' and columns[1]!='11': 

             if columns[1]=='201':
                break 

             repla =columns[0]
             compo=columns[3]
             print(repla,compo)  # this will print col1 and col4 of file2


  with open('20_3.2_10_100_18.txt') as s:

           while True:

                nuclide = s.readline()
                if not nuclide:
                   break

                rows = re.split(r"\s+",nuclide.strip())
                material = rows[0]
                com2 = rows[1]
                print(material,com2) # col1 and col2 from file1
```

the output should be like this:

```
     ag-109      101  0  3.905E-07  293   end  
     am-241      101  0  1.121E-06  293   end  
     am-243      101  0  7.294E-09  293   end  
     cs-133      101  0  1.210E-05  293   end  
     eu-151      101  0  2.393E-08  293   end  
     eu-153      101  0  4.918E-07  293   end  
     gd-155      101  0  2.039E-08  293   end
```

....
....
....

i am really beginner in Python. i don't know how to finish it. 
i don't know how to write the complete file after editing too.

please any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your requirement is not clear, can you add a sample output ?

Comment: @VikasP thanks for your comment, i just added sample output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input files look like Fixed Width Fields text files. If you can use pandas, it can be easy:

```
# load the input files
df1 = pd.read_fwf('file1.txt', header=None)
df2 = pd.read_fwf('file2.txt', header=None)

# create an empty dataframe and feed it with the length of df1
df3 = pd.DataFrame()
df3[0] = df1[0]
df3[1] = df2.iloc[0:len(df1), 1]
df3[2] = df2.iloc[0:len(df1), 2]
df3[3] = df1[1]
df3[4] = df2.iloc[0:len(df1), 4]
df3[5] = df2.iloc[0:len(df1), 5]

# output a file
with open('output.txt', 'w') as fd:
    fd.write(df3.to_string(header=False, index=False))
```

---

After your edit, pandas is not an option, so you should read both files at the same time and write each line of the output file still at the same time. Code could be:

```
with open(file1) as f1, open(file2) as f2, open(outfile, 'w') as fout:
    sep = re.compile(r'\s+')    # compile the separator for re
    while True:
        # read a line from each file
        try:
            line1 = next(f1)
            line2 = next(f2)
        except StopIteration:
            break                # stop processing on end of any file

        # split lines in fields
        fields1 = sep.split(line1.strip())
        fields2 = sep.split(line2.strip())

        if fields2[1] != '101':
            break                # stop processing if past 101

        # replace fields and write a line on the output file    
        fields2[0] = fields1[0]
        fields2[3] = fields1[1]
        fout.write(' {}      {}  {}  {}  {}   {} \n'.format(*fields2))
```

The output file looks like the expected file of your question.

Comment: Thanks @Serge Bellesta, firstly,i could't install Pandas, second thing, that my text file is not fixed width, just in the first 200 lines like the above, the rest is much different. 
how is to be working for the only lines i want please ?

Comment: @rawash: The informations given in the question should be enough for other to be able to answer. That means that you should exactly describe the input files, the output file and the processing between. Said differently, if you do not give that, I won't be able to guess and help.

Comment: Bellesta, thanks for your recommendations, i will edit it now and make it more clear. hopefully i would get the help. and i will be very thankful.

Comment: Bellesta, I have edited and added more clarifications, i wish its clear now.
hope that you could help me with this.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks its working well,
i have one more concern, how to continue reading the file after changing is happened ? because as i mentioned, the file after the columns, continues in mixture of text and numbers with different columns widths.
appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

One can use `dataframe` from `pandas` to replace columns from one to other.

Try following code (comments show what is being done):

```
df = pd.read_csv('file1.txt', sep='\s+', header=None)
df2 = pd.read_csv('file2.txt', sep='\s+', header=None)
df2[0] = df[0]  # replace column in 2nd dataframe with column in first.
df2[3] = df[1]  # similarly replace another column.
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
        0    1  2             3    4    5
0  ag-109  101  0  3.905000e-07  293  end
1  am-241  101  0  1.121000e-06  293  end
2  am-243  101  0  7.294000e-09  293  end
3  cs-133  101  0  1.210000e-05  293  end
4  eu-151  101  0  2.393000e-08  293  end
5  eu-153  101  0  4.918000e-07  293  end
6  gd-155  101  0  2.039000e-08  293  end
```

To write to a file:

```
df2.to_csv('outfile.txt', sep=' ', index=False, header=False)
```

Output of file:

```
ag-109 101 0 3.9049999999999996e-07 293 end
am-241 101 0 1.121e-06 293 end
am-243 101 0 7.294000000000001e-09 293 end
cs-133 101 0 1.21e-05 293 end
eu-151 101 0 2.3930000000000003e-08 293 end
eu-153 101 0 4.918e-07 293 end
gd-155 101 0 2.0390000000000003e-08 293 end
```

To select particular rows by criteria, one can write:

```
newdf = df2[(df2[0] == 'u-235') | (df2[0]=='u-238')]
print(newdf)
```

Output:

```
       0    1  2         3    4    5
1  u-235  101  0  0.000526  293  end
3  u-238  101  0  0.022780  293  end
```

Comment: Thank you @ rnso
how is it to be done for specific lines, since i have to replace only some lines but the rest of the file2 is way different text ?

Comment: I have added code for this also in my answer above.